# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select, tsx, react-fullstack

I have been working on react-select component which renders dropdown menu(Image mentioned below). It selects the value from the dropdown by default even though I have not selected it.

[Here is the Dropdown menu picture it renders and it selects 60 minutes value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPWNt.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { uniqueId } from 'lodash';
import Select from 'react-select';
import LabelWrapper from '../LabelWrapper';
import AlertWrapper from '../AlertWrapper';

const styles = require('./styles.module.scss');

type Props = {
  multi: boolean;
  options: Array<{ label: string; value: string }>;
  onChange: (selectElementValue: { label: string; value: string }) => {};
  onBlur: () => {};
  value: { value: string, label: string};
  error: string;
  placeholder: string;
  label: string;
  horizontalLabel: boolean;
  required?: boolean;
};

class CreatableSelect extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  inputId: string;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputId = uniqueId('id_');
  }

  render() {
    const disabled = this.props.options.length === 0;

    return (
      <LabelWrapper
        forId={this.inputId}
        error={!!this.props.error}
        label={this.props.label}
        horizontal={this.props.horizontalLabel}
        required={this.props.required}
      >
        <AlertWrapper>
          <Select.Creatable
            multi={this.props.multi}
            options={this.props.options}
            onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e.value)}
            disabled={disabled}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            className={this.props.error ? styles.hasError : null}
            onBlur={this.props.onBlur}
            value={this.props.value}
            inputProps={{ id: this.inputId }}
          />
        </AlertWrapper>
        {this.props.error && (
          <span className="help-block">{this.props.error}</span>
        )}
      </LabelWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export { CreatableSelect };
```

However, I want to clear the value from the dropdown but, it gives me error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

what is possibly going wrong in my code?

Comment: Something to the left of `.value` is null, so look at all of the places where `.value` shows up... It's either `this.props` or `e`. Since `this.props` is used in a lot of place, it's probably `e`. Apparently whatever `Select.Creatable` is, it's not providing `e` when emitting the `onChange` event.

Comment: Yes, I think the it's e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `react-select` [docs](https://react-select.com/props), here is the `onChange` event's first parameter, `newValue`

> newValue: IsMulti extends true ? ReadonlyArray<Option> : SingleValue One of<null, Option>

So, it's possible for `newValue` to be `null`. You'll have to do a `null` check or use any other syntax that enables you to do so.

The API might not be intuitive to somebody used to using `onChange` on a `select` directly, but they've chosen it and you'll have to abide by it if you want to use it.

Some examples of what you could do:

1. `e && e.value`
2. `e?.value`
3. `e && this.props.onChange(e.value)`

And probably you want to change the parameter name on your event handler to `newValue` or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, What would be the reason that dropdown is selecting the default value as 60 Minutes? Initially I want that dropdown to be empty but with the current situation it's not.

Comment: May have to do with what you're passing in `value`.